# Proving Stability of a Function of Laguerre Polynomials

Tags: derivatives, stability-theory, laguerre-polynomials

I'm trying to prove that the following potential is stable at its critical point:

$$
F_{\textbf{n}}(x) = x - \sum_{\ell=1}^{r} \ln G_{n_{\ell}}(x),
$$

where $\textbf{n} = (n_1, n_2, \ldots, n_r)$ and

$$ G_{n}(x) = \sum_{j=0}^{n} \binom{n}{j}\frac{x^{j}}{j!} \equiv L_{n}(-x)$$

with $L_{n}(-x)$ $n$th Laguerre polynomial. From plotting $F_{\textbf{n}}(x)$ as a function of $x$ for a few sets of $\textbf{n}$ values, it appears that the potential is always stable, but I am seeking an analytical proof.

---

**Solution Attempt**

The critical point $x = \bar{x}$ is defined by

\begin{equation}
0 = 1 - \sum_{\ell=1}^r \frac{G_{n_{\ell}}'(\bar{x})}{G_{n_{\ell}}(\bar{x})} = 1 - \frac{1}{\bar{x}} \sum_{\ell=1}^r n_{\ell} \left(1- \frac{G_{n_{\ell}-1}(\bar{x})}{G_{n_{\ell}}(\bar{x})}\right)
\end{equation}
Where the final expression comes from the Laguerre Polynomial identity $x G_n'(x) = n(G_n(x) - G_{n-1}(x))$.

We can show that the second derivative of the potential is given by
\begin{align}
F_{\textbf{n}}''(\bar{x}) & = \sum_{\ell=1}^r \left[  \left(\frac{G_{n_{\ell}}'(\bar{x})}{G_{n_{\ell}}(\bar{x})}\right)^2 -  \frac{G_{n_{\ell}}''(\bar{x})}{G_{n_{\ell}}(\bar{x})}\right]\\[.75em]
& =\sum_{\ell=1}^r \left[  \left(\frac{G_{n_{\ell}}'(\bar{x})}{G_{n_{\ell}}(\bar{x})}\right)^2 -  \frac{1}{\bar{x}}\frac{-(1+ \bar{x})G_{n_{\ell}}'(\bar{x})+ n_{\ell}G_{n_{\ell}}(\bar{x})}{G_{n_{\ell}}(\bar{x})}\right] \\[.75em]
& =\sum_{\ell=1}^r  \left(\frac{G_{n_{\ell}}'(\bar{x})}{G_{n_{\ell}}(\bar{x})}\right)^2 +  \frac{1+ \bar{x}}{\bar{x}}\sum_{\ell=1}^r\frac{G_{n_{\ell}}'(\bar{x})}{G_{n_{\ell}}(\bar{x})} -  \frac{1}{\bar{x}}\sum_{\ell=1}^rn_{\ell} \\[.75em]
& = \frac{1}{\bar{x}^2}\sum_{\ell=1}^r n_{\ell}^2 \left(1- \frac{G_{n_{\ell}-1}(\bar{x})}{G_{n_{\ell}}(\bar{x})} \right)^2 + 1 + \frac{1-N}{\bar{x}}
\end{align}
In the second equality we used the identity $x G''_n(x)  = n G_{n}(x) - (1+x) G_n'(x)$ which can be established by differentiating both sides of $x G'_n(x) = n(G_n(x) - G_{n-1}(x)$ (1st Laguerre Polynomial identity) and  applying $G'_n(x) = G_{n-1}'(x) + G_{n-1}(x)$ (intentionally a sum and *not* a difference). In the final equality we used the critical point condition and defined $N \equiv \sum_{\ell=1}^{r} n_{\ell}$.

From the final line above, it is not clear to me how to show that $F_{\textbf{n}}''(\bar{x})$ is always positive. Any help, or alternative approaches would be appreciated.